# How to connect an aws sumerian acene with aws iot core?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot, amazon-sumerian

I am fairly new to AWS Sumerian and AWS IoT core, I want to send data from a raspberry pi to IoT core and simulate the same action in AWS Sumerian scene, I am able to form a communication between the raspberry pi and IoT core shadow but the data from shadow is not being read in Sumerian scene, I have used Cognito identity pool to connect IoT things shadow and Sumerian but whenever I try to run I land up with error:Cannot read property 'getThingShadow' of undefined
I can't seem to understand if this is due to some access issue or if the policy attached to my identity pool is missing something. I have followed the blog: https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/articles/training-digital-twin/

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank You!

I am attaching the screenshot of error
[image]

Comment: It appears that `window.AWSIotData` is not set. In Sumerian, under _AWS Configuration_, do you have **IoT Data Client** enabled?

Comment: Ya, it's enabled